# JPA in Netbeans, strange thing

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I encountered the following problem.
I have simple (just started) web application.
I created new Web Application project and generated entity with @ManyToOne (so there are to enitities in fact) class from the database. This is what happens when i try to run it.

First run:

`Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group WHERE (group_id = 1)' at line 1 Error Code: 1064 Call: SELECT group_id, acc_level, name FROM group WHERE (group_id = ?) bind => [1 parameter bound] Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="file:/D:/Projekty/Sell Your Thing/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_Sell_Your_ThingPU" referenceClass=Group1 )`

Second run: Everything is correct
After making Netbeans to recompile (for example I add a space somewhere) i get this:

```
com.model.User cannot be cast to com.model.User
```

After few refreshes of the page i get this:

```
WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

I am so confused right now:/
(I use glassfish and mysql)

edit:
I resolved the firt error by changing the name from group to user_group because its a keyword.
I also resolved the last error by adding

```
        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false"/>
    <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
```

in persistance.xml

I still cannot resolve the casting one. I don't understand why i have some class leak or whatever it is while I have really simple code. (generated entities in netbeans) 
method causing errors:

```
    public String getUserNameById(int id) {
    em = getEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserId");
    q.setParameter("userId", id);
    User u = (User) q.getSingleResult();
    em.close();
    return u.getName();
}
```

and i just use it in JSF

```
<h:outputText value="#{userBean.getUserNameById(2)}" />
```

Comment: `com.model.User cannot be cast to com.model.User` is a pretty good indicator that you have a [class loader leak](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html). You might see the issue crop up after frequent redeploys. Restarting Glassfish entirely should resolve the issue (until it happens again =p)

Comment: it do resolve but it do happen again. Too often

Answer (score 1):

The first error is likely caused by the fact that you chose `group` as the name of your table. `group` being a reserved SQL keyword, the query is invalid. Choose another name (and don't choose `select`, `order` or `insert` as the name :-))

Comment: You were right. I used a Group1 as a classname and I thought it's enough. I still have the other errors though.